# Notify users that vote against the majority of other users in the review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, notifications, review-suspension

I believe it would prove to be beneficial to notify<sup>1</sup> users that vote against the majority of other users in a review queue, for two main reasons,

1. Users that *want* to learn how to be more helpful to the community are now able to learn quicker, as they can more easily compare their judgment to the community's and adjust their reviewing methodology where necessary,
2. Users that simply click-away without paying a blind bit of notice to what they are reviewing (yet manage to avoid failing audits) are now forced to vote appropriately.

[For example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reMWb.png), lets say User A reviews a "bad" post that obviously needs to be closed, but, rather chooses to vote for no action to be taken while every other reviewer takes the appropriate action (flagging for the post to be closed).

After the post is closed User A would be notified that his/her decision was incorrect, thus allowing the user to learn more easily from their mistake(s) and hopefully review more accurately in the future (that's if User A is of the "willing to learn" type, rather than the "I just want badges" kind, which would just result in the user getting banned).

There are two possible disadvantages that I've identified,

1. If, by some remote chance, the majority of reviewers all happen to vote incorrectly, the "newbie" user will not be notified (and not learn that they voted incorrectly), which  isn't the end of the world. But there is also a possible advantage to this, if there happens to be a knowledgeable reviewer among the notified users he/she could flag the incorrect decision, thus helping to guide even more users onto the "straight and narrow" path to reviewing correctly.
2. User A could be bombarded with notifications telling him/her that their judgement was incorrect. Which again has a partial flip side, if the user is a genuine "robo-reviewer", this bombardment could be seen as a possible "punishment" for robo-reviewing.

---

<sup>1</sup> Which could *possibly* lead to a temporary ban/suspension if this behaviour consistently continues.

Comment: I think the general idea has been presented before, and part of the objection was that too often, the 'majority' are voting badly; so voting against the majority may not be as helpful. Even if such notifications are 'wrong' just 20% of the time, that would really confuse people, I think.

Comment: @AndrewBarber From what I've seen (admittedly that's not *loads*) I would have said the voting majority aren't voting *that badly* to the point where there's only 1 "good" reviewer per review; are there maybe some statistics to prove this?

Comment: I think it's all anecdotal at this point, but I know I've seen lots where there were five bad reviews against one good one. Stats would be nice, but hard to do, since so much of it is subjective.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I see, but would this occurrence (however rare or common) outweigh the advantages?

Comment: I think such a notification would carry *extreme* weight; people would consider it to be Absolute Canon. Yet, that's not what it is. And I don't think any amount of text qualifying it would affect that.

Comment: +1 "Your vote was REJECTED by others in the review queue ***and you should feel bad!***"

Comment: I would not like it because for all the tag only edit robo approved edit reviews I would be the one being notified all the time and being remembered all over again that I am in the minority of people not wanting to approve addition of tons of nonsensical tags.

Comment: It would not necessarily be an incorrect review at all, even without considering robo-reviewers.  There are **multiple** posts where there is more than one correct close reason.

Comment: A little remark: if voting with the minority is punishable, there is no need for vote et al.

Comment: So in other words, encourage groupthink and towing the party line?  No thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the majority action is actually correct in most all cases then *we don't have a problem in the first place, and there is nothing we need to do at all* because after all we're, by definition, taking the right action.  The system is designed to handle a small percentage of incapable/malicious users.  What it *can't* deal with as having enough bad users that the wrong action is frequently taken.  If you get to that point (and many of the queues *do* have that problem) then this change makes things worse, not better, because you end up telling users taking the correct action that they're doing something wrong, and even end up banning you're few *good* users from reviewing, leaving around just your bad reviewers.

So in short, if things are fine already then this change doesn't really do anything at all, because things are fine.

If things aren't already fine (which is the case) then it makes things get much, much worse.

Under no circumstances is this change actually *helpful*.

Comment: It is actually useful if someone is going against the majority, that person can learn in time before getting used to bad habits and then later educate that on. Otherwise, the next generation may grow over the head of the older who knows how the site is supposed to work. This change is definitely not black and white as you present it. It has pros and cons, so your answer is quite unfair.

Comment: @lpapp But the person going against the majority may well be the person taking the correct course of action.  You should be teaching people to take the correct action, not to take the same action as everyone else.  There are ways of going about doing the former, but this is only doing the latter.

Answer (score 8):

[Groupthink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink) is generally regarded as bad. This is an actual implementation of groupthink.

- If the first 3 users were right, why are we requiring 5 votes? Why not just close it (if they voted to close) then and there?
- If the first 3 users agree and the next dissents, shouldn't that vote be given as much weight as if it were the first? Instead of being corralled over?

Comment: If groupthink is "generally regarded as bad", then doesn't that suggest groupthink might be good? (Hi, welcome to Meta!)

Comment: @CodyGray ugh, you got me. But to humorlessly answer, no, groupthink is more specific than consensus or majority opinion.